# An object is validated via a try-catch block. Why does the LSP recognize its type incorrectly?

Tags: typescript, language-server-protocol

```js
function parseAndValidate(obj: unknown): ParsedObj | void {
    try {
        // do a lot of validations
        return parsedObj
    } catch {
        throw new Error('obj is invalid') 
    } 
} 
const parsedObj = parseAndValidate(obj)
```

I have two questions:

- The LSP recognizes `parsedObj` has type `any`. Why is that?
- Why doesn't it recognize `parsedObj` has type `ParsedObj`, because otherwise an error will be thrown?

As the result, I have to force type it by using `as ParsedObj`.

Comment: Why is the return type `| void`? As you say, if it cannot be parsed it throws, and the consumer _should_ use the return value.

Comment: "*The LSP recognizes parsedObj has type any*" doesn't seem to be the case here; https://tsplay.dev/mMp9kN

Comment: "*Why doesn't it recognize parsedObj has type ParsedObj, because otherwise an error will be thrown?*" the return type seems to also be `ParsedObj | void` exactly like the function is typed: https://tsplay.dev/w6eDrW

Comment: Also FYI https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, I just want to explicitly that there is a possibility that an error will be thrown. I thought `void` is the suitable one. Removing it does get `parsedObj` get the correct type

Comment: @VLAZ hmm, I use the Deno LSP for VS Code

Comment: @Ooker  Use `never` for self-documentation in that case, not `void`.  TS is simply going to ignore it, as `anything | never` resolves to simply `anything`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because I didn't declare the `ParsedObj` type!

In [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApygZwgEwPIBGAVsgN4BQyVymA9gLYSpS0AOAXDWFKAOYDc5AL7lyMAK4gEYYLRDJWGbAEEQOAGpwANsBxxIAClrFOkgNYhaAdxABKTuiy5CJAD7IAbrV1lK1bgCevtQhyAD0Ycg4tMhwyFq0YMi0MJ7auvqyIJh+ochQEGDiUPKKTvjEuchCyAj6CAAWwXnIYA0sVsggEJ0AolAsUAYA5MYkwJjIoB7pOMO2yFU1wovkOBAIWhgoCHKYSWOmIBbWIIK72Ull2BUkALwKShCqGrP6EEbEC+QRoQB6AH5yEA), the type for `parsedObj` returns as expected (`ParsedObj | void`). If you remove the declaration it will return `any`.

As for the question 2, removing `void` will help the LSP recognizes `parsedObj` to always have type `ParsedObj`. As [Julio Di Egidio says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769590/an-object-is-validated-via-a-try-catch-block-why-does-the-lsp-recognize-its-typ?noredirect=1#comment137105521_77769590), use `never` for self-documentation in that case, not `void`. TS is simply going to ignore it, as `Anything | never` resolves to simply `Anything`.